# android detect drag only inside image

Tags: android, events, imageview, motion

A finger drag in a vertical motion (up/down) should only be detected inside the image of the imageview, not outside. However, in the area above the image it detects the drag. No where else is a drag detected, nor on the left, right or the bottom but only in the area directly above the image. It works inside the image but also outside above it, which it shouldn't do. I've tried a number of things to resolve this but nothing has worked. Can someone please help?

So, in my onCreate in my activity I have the method that was created to scale the image:

```
redShape = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
scaleImage();
```

In Motion event, action down:

```
rect = new Rect(redShape.getLeft(),redShape.getTop(),redShape.getRight(),redShape.getBottom());
```

In action move:

```
 if (rect.contains(posX, posY)){
```

In the if statement above I just have the code that counts whenever a drag is made.

EDIT 1:

```
     drawableHeight = drawable2.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
     drawableWidth = drawable2.getIntrinsicWidth(); 

     drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, drawableWidth, drawableHeight);
     m.mapRect(drawableRect);
```

Do I do this next (by the way, redShape is the imageview):

```
     redShape.setImageMatrix(m);
```

In rect.contains(posX,posY) do I change that to drawableRect.contains(posX,posY)?

EDIT 2:

```
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);


        Log.i(" test 3 ", "width : " + redShape.getWidth() + "height: " + redShape.getHeight());



    }
```

Comment: "`I've scaled my image to match the imageview`" wrong, ImageView draws the Bitmap/Drawable with different sizes depending on scaleType, no need for "image scaling"

Comment: yea you're right, removed that and I get the exact same result. It still detects a drag above the image. I don't understand why it's fine anywhere else around the image except for the top.

Comment: ImageView internally uses a Matrix, for ex if your bitmap is 100x100 and your VimageView is 400x400 your Matrix is set in such way that point [0,0] is mapped to [0,0] and [100,100] is mapped to [400,400], you can use mapPoints to do the point(s) mapping

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to use map points and map the coordinates of the image to the imageview, would it be ok if you showed me an example of how to use it?

Comment: try Matrix#mapRect where rect is (0, 0, bitmap_width, bitmap_height)

Comment: Check my edit please, I've done the above and am not sure about the next step.

Comment: did you try to inspect  `drawableRect` ? log it?

Comment: yea I get: rectF(0.0,0.0,251.0,293.0)

Comment: so your Bitmap is mapped to that RectF

Comment: But now it's even worse, it doesn't detect the touch inside the image at all, it only detects a touch on the left-top of the screen, above the image.

Comment: whats the size of your Bitmap, size of your ImageView and ImageView's scaleType?

Comment: image size: width: 251 Height: 293
ImageView size: width: 0 Height: 0, How do you get imageview's scaleType? Also, is it odd that the width and height of imageview is 0?

Comment: ImageView size: width: 0 Height: 0, ? so ImageView size is ZERO pixels x ZERO pixels ? use ViewTreeObserver to get the size after layout phase and do the mapping then or do the mapping in touch listener

Comment: See my edit 2, I did that outside of onCreate and I got the actual width and height of the imageview which is 251, 293 just like the image size?

Comment: override onSizeChanged if you  have custom ImageView,  and call getImageMatrix there and mapRect

Comment: and what, did it work?

Comment: I'm trying to use onSizeChanged but I think I might be doing it wrong, I haven't used that before so it's a bit confusing. Could you show me an example of how I can implement it. Also, how can I call getImageMatrix from within the custom imageview class because the class extends imageview so wouldn't that be done outside this class and inside the main activity?

Comment: Is there a way without having custom imageview class?

Comment: sure: just get the matrix in your touch listener, you will be sure that matrix is already set and valid